# Error while executing a Ms Access db through nodejs

Tags: node.js, ms-access

I am trying to access a Ms Access 2007 db trough nodejs in Windows 7, but even this simple query won't work. I receive the following message in the command prompt (this is a translation, the original is in portuguese): "Operation not allowed when object is closed". Anybody have any answers? The javascript code is written below:

```
var ADODB = require('node-adodb');
    var connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\teste\\dbteste.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;');

ADODB.debug = true;
connection
  .query('SELECT * FROM [Tabela];')
  .on('done', function (data){
    console.log('Result:'.green.bold, data);
  })
  .on('fail', function (data){
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the connectionString :

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\teste\\dbteste.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

by

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\teste\\dbteste.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Also, check if the `.accdb` path is right.

Moreover, add `ADODB.encoding = 'iso-8859-15';` for portuguese encoding.

I'm not sure but you may replace `[Tabela]` by simply `Tabela`. The `;` at the sql query end is not necessary.

Comment: Still nothing !! :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: I had to save my database to an old format (mdb). It looks like this library or the driver cannot read .accdb files.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue too. This seems to be a [bug in node-adodb module](https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb/issues/9).(last seen at 8/31/2015)

In the linked page you can see that two people have encountered the same problem and the developer of node-adodb has asked them to upload the example( on 7/17/2015)